# Invalid JSON response Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

im trying to to make use of the datatables but when is supossed to draw the table the response is:

DataTables warning: table id=tablaSucursales - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

And it appears two times

My object response is like this

```
{
    Mensaje: "OK"
    "Data": [
        {
            "Id_Sucursal": 510001,
            "Nombre_Sucursal": "Pedestal Prueba",
            "Estado": "CDMX",
            "Activa": 0
        },
        {
            "Id_Sucursal": 510010,
            "Nombre_Sucursal": "Tableta de Pruebas",
            "Estado": "CDMX",
            "Activa": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

My ajax request and datatables initialization is like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: './Archivos_Ajax.asp',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { accion: "ObtenerSucursales",
                PageNumber: 1,
                RowsOfPage: 20 },
        success: function (response) {
      
            $('#tablaSucursales').DataTable( {
                // "processing": true,
                // "serverSide": true,
                data: response.Data,
                // search: {
                //  return: true
                // },
                columns: [
                    {title: "Id_Sucursal" },
                    {title: "Nombre_Sucursal"},
                    {title: "Estado"},
                    {title: "Activa"}
                ]
            } );

        }
    });
```

I already validate the Data object with https://jsonlint.com/

Any help would be awesome

Comment: Check the documentation: you are using [`columns.title`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title). You need to use [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data). And if you have trouble finding those references for yourself, then start by looking at the [examples](https://datatables.net/examples/index) - especially the [Ajax examples](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) - and the one which uses JSON data objects, the same as your data source.

Comment: Also use `data` with a lower case "d" not upper case in your array.

Answer (score 1):

From the data format you have provided, please see the changes I have made to your column definitions/initializations. It should be as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        url: './Archivos_Ajax.asp',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { accion: "ObtenerSucursales",
                PageNumber: 1,
                RowsOfPage: 20 },
        success: function (response) {
      
            $('#tablaSucursales').DataTable( {
                // "processing": true,
                // "serverSide": true,
                data: response.Data,
                // search: {
                //  return: true
                // },
                columns: [
                    {"data" : "Data.Id_Sucursal" },
                    {"data" : "Data.Nombre_Sucursal"},
                    {"data" : "Data.Estado"},
                    {"data" : "Data.Activa"}
                ]
            } );

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this example as a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/g7ntd8rk/12/

JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      "Id_Sucursal": 510001,
      "Nombre_Sucursal": "Pedestal Prueba",
      "Estado": "CDMX",
      "Activa": 0
    },
    {
      "Id_Sucursal": 510010,
      "Nombre_Sucursal": "Tableta de Pruebas",
      "Estado": "CDMX",
      "Activa": 0
    },
  ];

  var json = data;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      data: json
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#lista_proiecte').DataTable({
        "data": json,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "Id_Sucursal"
          },
          {
            "data": "Nombre_Sucursal"
          },
          {
            "data": "Estado"
          },
          {
            "data": "Activa"
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  });
})
```

HTML:

```html
<!--css plugins for table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">


<!--js plugins for table-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<section class="container shadow">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="lista_proiecte" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id_Sucursal</th>
          <th>Nombre_Sucursal</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Activa</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Although this works in your example, the data variable you created is not mimicking the one OP is receiving from the AJAX request, so in OP case, it will not work. There is the response, then a nested array of objects within "Data", so Data.objKey needs to be called to actually init the column data ;)